# noexcept(false) Destructor overrides all special member functions' exception specification?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, language-lawyer

Consider this Class `T`

```
struct T{ 
    T() noexcept (true) {}
    T(T&& ) noexcept (true) {}          
    T(const T& ) noexcept (true) {}

    T& operator = (T&&) noexcept(true) { return *this; }
    T& operator = (const T&) noexcept(true) { return *this; }

    ~T() noexcept(false) {}
};
```

Consider this simple test program:

```
int main(){
    constexpr bool default_ctor = noexcept(T());
    static_assert(default_ctor == true, "Default Constructor can throw exceptions");

    constexpr bool move_ctor = noexcept(T(std::declval<T>())); //Move ctor
    static_assert(move_ctor == true, "Move Constructor can throw exceptions");

    constexpr bool copy_ctor = noexcept(T(std::declval<T&>())); //Copy ctor
    static_assert(copy_ctor == true, "Copy Constructor can throw exceptions");

    constexpr bool move_assign = noexcept(std::declval<T>() = std::declval<T>());
    static_assert(move_ctor == true, "Move Assignment can throw exceptions");

    constexpr bool copy_assign = noexcept(std::declval<T&>() = std::declval<const T&>());
    static_assert(copy_ctor == true, "Copy Assignment can throw exceptions");


    //It doesn't matter when using *`type_traits`* either. Same behavior:
    constexpr bool no_throw_cons = std::is_nothrow_constructible<T>::value;
    static_assert(no_throw_cons == true, "Default Constructor isn't nothrow");
    //...others skipped for brevity
}
```

Every single `static_assert` here fires. This shouldn't be as per what I understand from the standard:

- [g++ (GCC) 6.1.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1cbcba73125ffc10)
- [clang (LLVM) 3.8.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8921fa2121a106d7)
- [MSVC (Visual Studio 2015)](http://rextester.com/LVP78241)

But, when you declare the destructor of `T` without an exception specification (same as `noexcept(true)` in this simple context), all asserts pass!

- [g++ (GCC) 6.1.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4833fce1117a30a4)
- [clang (LLVM) 3.8.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34751a570ff3f680)
- [MSVC (Visual Studio 2015)](http://rextester.com/ANRT98477)

---

However, the runtime respects the specification:

```
struct T{ 
    T() noexcept (true) { throw int(8); }
    //.... there rest omitted for brevity
    ~T() noexcept(false) {}
};

int main(){
    T a;
    (void)a;
};
```

`std::terminate` is called as expected.

- [g++ (GCC) 6.1.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fc87cc2f1376ade)
- [clang (LLVM) 3.8.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de2e7c67fec9361f)
- [MSVC (Visual Studio 2015)](http://rextester.com/UWX13894)

---

Is there any part of the C++ standard that defines or implies this behavior? That a `noexcept (false)` specifiier on a destructor overrides the exception specification of every special member function at compile-time only?

Or is this a Front-End bug in every major compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first test you're asking if the full expression `T()` can throw an exception. That expression constructs a `T` *and then destroys it again*. So if the destructor can throw, so can that expression.

Comment: Ohh... Yikes! I totally forgot about *full-expression*. Thanks. I just saw [this note on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible#Notes) too. But then, the note implies that whether the type trait `std::no_throw_constructible<T>::value` and it friends will be `true` if the destructor of `T` is `noexcept(true)`; is an open ended decision for compiler vendors, right? Meaning we cannot fully rely on this behavior for this kind of case.?

Comment: Ok. Thanks. (sorry for the comment mixup)